# Android Studio Doesn't Load the Preview Layout with no Error

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

Android Studio Doesn't Load the Preview Layout and there's no Error! but when I open an old project it loads that projects layouts.

[image: Screen Shot]

I tried the older build tools and I also delete cache and stuff like that, I even removed entire android studio and reinstalled but it didn't fix it.

It seems to be happening since the fresh Windows 10 that I installed recently, and the the Android Studio V3.1.3.

Any solution?

Comment: what do you have in your xml layout?

Comment: Set the sdk to 27 in the preview to test?

Comment: Run updates also

Comment: a button but, thats not the point, what ever  I put there it just doesn't load it.

Comment: I set the sdk to 26, 25 none of them fixed.

Comment: the thing is that, I dont see this problem in the older projects, only happens when I open new project

Comment: click the red i button up right to see errors

Comment: I lowered my API to 26, it got fixed.